# Prove that this set is countable using the counting measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be the counting measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$, and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ a measurable positive function. If $f$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$, prove that $A = \{ x\in \mathbb R : f(x) > 0\}$ is countable.

I have showed that this holds when $f$ is a simple positive function, but don't know to generalize the result to when $f$ is a positive function. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following: for each $n$, the set $\{ x: f(x) > 1/n\}$  must be finite (why?). Note the countable union of finite sets is countable.

Comment: We have $\frac{1}{n}1_{\{f > \frac{1}{n}\}} \leq f \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\mu(\{ f > \frac{1}{n}\}) \leq \int_{\Omega}fd \mu< \infty$, which means that $\{ f > \frac{1}{n}\}$ is finite. Then writing $A = \{ f>0\}  = \cup_{n\geq 1} \{ f > \frac{1}{n}\}$ concludes the proof. Did I get it right?

Comment: Very nice! That looks good to me.